# During testing, controller can't set session variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm using MvcContrib.TestHelper like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void LogOut() {

    // Arrange

    var controller = new AdminController(new AdminLogics(new AdminRepositoryStub()));
    var builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
    builder.InitializeController(controller);

    controller.Session["AdminIsLoggedIn"] = true;

    // Act

    var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.LogOut();

    // Assert

    Assert.IsFalse((bool)controller.Session["AdminIsLoggedIn"]);
}
```

However the assert fails since the session var is not overwritten.

Here's controller:

```
public ActionResult LogOut() {
    Session["AdminIsLoggedIn"] = false;

    return RedirectToAction("List", "Catalogue");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Session variables can only be accessed when running under the context of a HttpContext. Your test methods are not running under the HttpContext. It will be difficult to test but perhaps this post will help you.

http://haacked.com/archive/2005/06/11/simulating_httpcontext.aspx